# Swift - set cornerRadius and shadow at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to set a `cornerRadius` and a `shadow`(bottom + right) to my `UICollectionViewCell` but my code doesn't work. Neither the cornerRadius nor the shadow does appear..

Here's my code:

```
class MainWishlistCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let wishlistImage: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.image = UIImage(named: "logoGroß")
    return v
}()

let wishlistLabel: UILabel = {
    let v = UILabel()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.text = "Main Wishlist"
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 18)
    v.textColor = .darkGray
    v.textAlignment = .center
    return v
}()

func addShadow() {
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.wishlistImage.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowRadius = cornerRadius
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.wishlistImage.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
}



func commonInit() -> Void {
    addShadow()
    contentView.addSubview(wishlistImage)
    contentView.addSubview(wishlistLabel)
    // constrain view to all 4 sides
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        wishlistImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        wishlistImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        wishlistImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        wishlistImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150),

        wishlistLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistImage.bottomAnchor,constant: 1),
        wishlistLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        wishlistLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        wishlistLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    ])


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one line of code into `addShadow()` function:

```
layer.masksToBounds = false ---> which set the shadow of the view's layer.
```

Then add corner radius to your cell:

```
contentview.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at that point

```
addShadow()
contentView.addSubview(wishlistImage)
contentView.addSubview(wishlistLabel)
```

The image `bounds` is zero

```
self.wishlistImage.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: 
             self.wishlistImage.bounds, 
             cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
```

So you need

```
var once = true 
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   if once {
      addShadow()
      once = false
   }
}
```

Comment: where exactly do I have to implement that snippet? Sorry, not very experienced :)

Comment: inside `MainWishlistCell` class

Comment: that doesn't do anything for me